# PHP socket_recv and socket_read

Tags: php

From reading the PHP manual, socket_recv and socket_read function looks 
same to me, both function get data from client.

can any one tell me what are different between those 2 functions?

Comment: It seems `socket_recv` is a lower level function with more control and `socket_read` is easier higher level function with less control

Answer (score 15):

`socket_recv` returns the number of bytes received
`socket_read` returns the data that has been received

With `socket_recv` you can read bytes from the buffer AND know how many bytes have been recevied. With `socket_read` you can only read a specific amount of data from the buffer

Comment: This is the correct answer. The other one is confusing at best.

Comment: All the answers together form the Megazord Answer.

Answer (score 2):

From http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/socket/#b:

> 2.18.  What is the difference between read() and recv()?
>
> From Andrew Gierth (andrew@erlenstar.demon.co.uk):
>
> read() is equivalent to recv() with a flags parameter of 0.  Other
>   values for the flags parameter change the behaviour of recv().
>   Similarly, write() is equivalent to send() with flags == 0.

Comment: OP asks for PHP functions, the unix read() does not return string. Your link also states that read() must be expected to return 0, while the PHP socket_read() returns data

Comment: @barts what does that have to do with anything? The php functions call those functions in PHP internally. `PHP_FUNCTION(socket_read)` calls `recv` with 0 flags, while `PHP_FUNCTION(socket_recv)` calls `recv` with the flags you passed in PHP.

Comment: That can be, but its not what the OP asks

Comment: What I meant is that OP wants to know the differences of the two functions and not what are the similarities internally

Comment: @barts but because PHP pretty much doesn't do any work other than calling those internal functions, the difference between the internal functions is relatively the same as the difference between the thin wrappers. PHP's `socket_read` uses `0` as flags, while with `socket_recv` you can set the flags, that's the same difference as with the internal functions.

Comment: And that's a Good Thing™

Answer (score 1):

```
MSG_WAITALL  Block until at least len are received. However, if a signal is caught or the remote host disconnects, the function may return less data.
MSG_DONTWAIT     With this flag set, the function returns even if it would normally have blocked.
```

A blocking ability which will let the function wait untill a data received of course by using the socket_recv, but by using socket_read it assumes that bytes already received and does not wait, so it may return nothing:

```
Note:

socket_read() returns a zero length string ("") when there is no more data to read.
```